# Test for the presence of a value and, if so, if other cells in that row fall within range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm attempting to check one list of roadways (each has a unique identifier) against a separate list in Excel. If that roadway on the first list is present on the second I then want to see if it also falls within the milepoints on the second list (for both lists I have a column with for the beginning milepoint and a column for the ending milepoint).

The formula (located in cell CC3) I have that is checking for the roadway on the second list is this:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!CA3,'Sheet2'!Y:Y,1,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!CA3,'Sheet2'!Y:Y,1,FALSE))
```

I'm attempting to write a formula in another column that will check to see if the milepoints from the first sheet fall within the milepoints on the second sheet. Here is the formula for that:

```
=IF(AND(CC3<>"",F3>='Sheet2'!F2,G3<='Sheet2'!G2),"YES","")
```

Column F is the beginning milepoint and Column G is the ending milepoint on both sheets.

I realized that this formula isn't doing what I want since the second and third logic tests are simply looking at those respective cells on Sheet 2, not at the Column F & G values on the same row where it found the matching roadway unique identifier. How would I go about fixing this? I can seem to reason my way through it. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: replace `'Sheet2'!F2` in the 2nd formula with a vlookup or index\match to get the start / end for the desired roadway

Comment: I attempted something similar to that, but there is an error in it somewhere that I am not seeing. Here was my attempt:      =IF('Sheet1'!CC3<>"",INDEX('Sheet1'!Y:Y,MATCH('Sheet1'!CC3,'Sheet2'!Y:Y,0)-19),"NO")

Comment: Based on what I see in the formulas, this should work. Replace `'Sheet2'!F2` with `Index('Sheet2'!F:F,Match(F3,'Sheet2'!Y:Y,0))` and do same for `G2` reference.